# not able to clone github repo with ssh

Tags: windows, git, github, ssh

I am using windows 10, with Cygwin (for unix commands), and (git, OpenSSH) from scoop.

Error:

```
❯ git clone git@github.com:tshrpl/avis.git
Cloning into 'avis'..
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

SSH debug output:

```
❯ ssh -Tvvv git@github.com
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.9p1, LibreSSL 3.4.3
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/hitus/.ssh/config error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> 'C:\\Users\\hitus/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> 'C:\\Users\\hitus/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug2: resolving "github.com" port 22
debug3: resolve_host: lookup github.com:22
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to github.com [13.234.176.102] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/hitus/.ssh/id_rsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/hitus/.ssh/id_rsa.pub error:2
debug3: failed to open file:C:/Users/hitus/.ssh/id_rsa error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\hitus/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/hitus/.ssh/id_rsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/hitus/.ssh/id_rsa-cert.pub error:2
debug3: failed to open file:C:/Users/hitus/.ssh/id_rsa-cert error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\hitus/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/hitus/.ssh/id_ecdsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/hitus/.ssh/id_ecdsa.pub error:2
debug3: failed to open file:C:/Users/hitus/.ssh/id_ecdsa error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\hitus/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/hitus/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/hitus/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert.pub error:2
debug3: failed to open file:C:/Users/hitus/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\hitus/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/hitus/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/hitus/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk.pub error:2
debug3: failed to open file:C:/Users/hitus/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\hitus/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/hitus/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/hitus/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert.pub error:2
debug3: failed to open file:C:/Users/hitus/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\hitus/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\hitus/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/hitus/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/hitus/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert.pub error:2
debug3: failed to open file:C:/Users/hitus/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\hitus/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/hitus/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/hitus/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk.pub error:2
debug3: failed to open file:C:/Users/hitus/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\hitus/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/hitus/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/hitus/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert.pub error:2
debug3: failed to open file:C:/Users/hitus/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\hitus/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/hitus/.ssh/id_xmss error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/hitus/.ssh/id_xmss.pub error:2
debug3: failed to open file:C:/Users/hitus/.ssh/id_xmss error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\hitus/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/hitus/.ssh/id_xmss-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/hitus/.ssh/id_xmss-cert.pub error:2
debug3: failed to open file:C:/Users/hitus/.ssh/id_xmss-cert error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\hitus/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/hitus/.ssh/id_dsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/hitus/.ssh/id_dsa.pub error:2
debug3: failed to open file:C:/Users/hitus/.ssh/id_dsa error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\hitus/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/hitus/.ssh/id_dsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/hitus/.ssh/id_dsa-cert.pub error:2
debug3: failed to open file:C:/Users/hitus/.ssh/id_dsa-cert error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\hitus/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-65a6644c
debug1: compat_banner: no match: babeld-65a6644c
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file C:\\Users\\hitus/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 1 keys from github.com
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/hitus/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen C:\\Users\\hitus/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512
,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@o
penssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecd
sa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com
,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com
,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256
debug2: compression ctos: none
debug2: compression stoc: none
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:p2QAMXNIC1TJYWeIOttrVc98/R1BUFWu3/LiyKgUfQM
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file C:\\Users\\hitus/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 1 keys from github.com
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/hitus/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen C:\\Users\\hitus/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\hitus/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug2: get_agent_identities: ssh_agent_bind_hostkey: communication with agent failed
debug3: write ERROR from cb(2):232, io:00000219C68446F0
debug1: get_agent_identities: ssh_fetch_identitylist: communication with agent failed
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\hitus/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\hitus/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\hitus/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\hitus/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:JYyA/L72AmyrIMX/S4w6aIS+4HTVQkDUWlhARj++5fI
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\hitus/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\hitus/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\hitus/.ssh/id_dsa
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@opens
sh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed2
5519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\hitus/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\hitus/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\hitus/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\hitus/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\hitus/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\hitus/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Offering public key: C:\\Users\\hitus/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:JYyA/L72AmyrIMX/S4w6aIS+4HTVQkDUWlhARj++5fI
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: C:\\Users\\hitus/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:JYyA/L72AmyrIMX/S4w6aIS+4HTVQkDUWlhARj++5fI
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: using publickey with ED25519 SHA256:JYyA/L72AmyrIMX/S4w6aIS+4HTVQkDUWlhARj++5fI
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using ssh-ed25519 SHA256:JYyA/L72AmyrIMX/S4w6aIS+4HTVQkDUWlhARj++5fI
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 52
Authenticated to github.com ([13.234.176.102]:22) using "publickey".
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: filesystem
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: received RSA key SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: received ECDSA key SHA256:p2QAMXNIC1TJYWeIOttrVc98/R1BUFWu3/LiyKgUfQM
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: received ED25519 key SHA256:+DiY3wvvV6TuJJhbpZisF/zLDA0zPMSvHdkr4UvCOqU
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching C:\\Users\\hitus/.ssh/known_hosts for github.com / (none)
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\hitus/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: hostkeys_find: found ssh-ed25519 key under different name/addr at C:\\Users\\hitus/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: hostkeys_find: found ssh-rsa key under different name/addr at C:\\Users\\hitus/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: hostkeys_find: found ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 key under different name/addr at C:\\Users\\hitus/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: hostkeys_find: found ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 key at C:\\Users\\hitus/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: hostkeys_find: found ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 key under different name/addr at C:\\Users\\hitus/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching C:\\Users\\hitus/.ssh/known_hosts2 for github.com / (none)
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/hitus/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: hostkeys file C:\\Users\\hitus/.ssh/known_hosts2 does not exist
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: 3 server keys: 2 new, 18446744073709551615 retained, 2 incomplete match. 0 to remove
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: host key found matching a different name/address, skipping UserKnownHostsFile update
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 32000 rmax 35000
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 88
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 96
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug2: chan_shutdown_read: channel 0: (i0 o1 sock -1 wfd 4 efd 6 [write])
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: obuf_empty delayed efd 6/(88)
Hi tshrpl! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
debug2: channel 0: written 88 to efd 6
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: chan_shutdown_write: channel 0: (i3 o1 sock -1 wfd 5 efd 6 [write])
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug3: send packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r43 i3/0 o3/0 e[write]/0 fd -1/-1/6 sock -1 cc -1 io 0x00/0x08)

debug3: send packet: type 1
Transferred: sent 2072, received 2376 bytes, in 0.6 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 3759.6, received 4311.2
debug1: Exit status 1
```

Comment: This might help https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/error-permission-denied-publickey

Comment: already did all these steps, doesn't help

Comment: Do you really need all the keys? Maybe try using just the relevant one.

Comment: how do i remove the un-relevant keys ?

Comment: when i run dir in the ~/.ssh folder, i see only 1 pair of keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when i run dir in the ~/.ssh folder, i see only 1 pair of key

Then check the public key is registered to your [GitHub SSH settings](https://github.com/settings/keys).

You should see there one key with its fingerprint.

Compare its fingerprint with yours (assuming your key is named `id_rsa.pub`):

```
ssh-keygen -l -f /path/to/keys/id_rsa.pub
```

That should be the same considering you do have a Welcome message:

```
Hi tshrpl! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

I just tested `git clone git@github.com:tshrpl/avis`: it does work.

Make sure you have not typed your first `git clone` command in a `sudo` (root) session.

The [OP tshrpl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13860039/tshrpl) reports in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72118475/not-able-to-clone-github-repo-with-ssh/72123132#comment127453341_72123132):

> after manually killing the `ssh-agent` process and restarting it, cloning over ssh works!!

Comment: i've added the pub key to the gpg and ssh keys page in github, but i still cant clone :( i ended up using https which works, also there's no sudo in windows to begin with

Comment: @tshrpl Do you have a `~/.ssh/config` file?

Comment: i dont have that file (C:\Users\hitus\.ssh\config)

Comment: @tshrpl OK, so the git clone with an SSH URL should work then.

Comment: yes, after manually killing the ssh-agent process and restarting it, cloning over ssh works!!